# How to detect the creation date of a webpage from its server

Tags: date, automation, server, html, creation

I'm trying to find a way to detect the creation date of a webpage from its server.  As for example when was this page [wwww.Amazon.com/fghhggg](http://wwww.Amazon.com/fghhggg) created? Is there a way to find it and automate it? Thank you for the clues

Comment: Amazon pages are dynamic, so there isn't really a page as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer is no. Occasionally you'll see a web page that returns this information in the headers, but for a site where the pages are generated from information in the database (like Amazon, or most other sites on the internet), asking for the "creation date" doesn't really make sense.

For example, imagine you're looking up product X on Amazon. Amazon's servers retrieve information from the database, put together an HTML document, and return it to you. What would the "creation date" be? The page didn't exist 5 seconds ago - it was just assembled for you - and it doesn't exist now that it's been sent to you. If you're looking for when the product was added to Amazon's database, that information *might* be available via Amazon's API.

Comment: @ Kryten Thank you for your reply...Yes I'm looking for when the product was added to  Amazon's server